# Woocommerce Customize Product Category Widgets To Include "All" Shop Archive Link

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but can we hook into the legacy WooCommerce Product Category widget?

If so can anyone show an example?

The reason that I'd like to do this is that I'd like to inject an "All" link, which both the legacy and new block widget are lacking. This would allow the user to quickly view "all" products (i.e Shop Archive) by clicking the sidebar vs. having to use the primary navigation.

Or is the best way to handle this via subclass, modify and registering a new widget?

Comment: Since WP 5.8 woocommerce recommend using Classic Widgets https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-widgets/ for legacy. But its strongly recommended to move to the new widget blocks. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/widgets/

Comment: @MartinMirchev - The problem being that neither the Legacy nor the new Block level widgets include an "All" link in the Category list that is output. They don't want to add this as a feature either as the suggestion on it on Github was closed.

The question was in relation to what is the best way to inject an "All" link into that list (either legacy or block). I'm not sure if there's a filter for that or if the best method would be via subclass and registering a new widget.

Comment: There is All option in new filter category widget. You can create your own widget which will be the best solution